# Django rest framework. Setting up dynamic routes

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, action

I am setting up an API for a blog. I configured the output of comments for the post
Here is a portion of my **views.py** with **@action**:

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/posts', APIPost)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**views.py**

```
...
    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
    def comments(self, request, pk=None):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post__id=pk)
            serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Now I can get all comments on a post at.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/{post_pk}/comments/
```

The **problem** is that I just can't figure out how to get a separate comment at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/{post_pk}/comments/{comment_pk}
```

I keep getting '404 Not Found' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another `CommentViewSet`. ([docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset))

> views.py

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

> urls.py

```py
from .views import CommentViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("api/posts", APIPost)
router.register("api/comments", CommentViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

and then you can retrieve by making a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/{pk}`.

---

also, in your code,

1. `@action(methods=['get'], detail=True)` it should be `@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)` instead because the `comments` action is to retrieve list of all comments. `detail=True` is for returning a single object.
2. You don't need to manually check for the `if request.method == 'GET'` as DRF is already doing that internally because you already specified `methods=["get"]`.

Comment: Eshaan7, hello! Thanks for the answer. I created a new class and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should define URL Path or Route to a certain Address for the comments to load .
Like you defined the `APIPost` model ...comment url route should be like below

```
router.register(r"comments", comments)
```